# Billiards in an ellipse -- a query from a proof

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, billiards

I am reading about billiards in an ellipse and am a little stuck on a couple of points in the following proof (see image).

[image]

My main doubt is the highlighted line at the bottom: "Notice that line $l$ bisects $\angle F_2 A F'_2$." I cannot quite understand this. Does the highlighted line before that imply that line $m$ is a normal to the tangent? Then it makes sense.

My idea was that if we join the line segment $F'_1 F'_2$, then $\triangle F'_1 A F'_2 \cong \triangle F_1 A F_2$. So, if we fold the outside triangle onto the triangle inside the ellipse, the crease on the paper would be the line $l$, right? I think the first highlighted line implies the second. But I cannot quite prove this in writing. Can somebody please help?

Thank you.

Comment: I can give you another proof of that theorem if you want?

Comment: @Aqua The proof is given on page 9 here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Park.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiKp7zOof_pAhWZ_XMBHa-vAi0QFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw2s348ah7wF-oA1LH-nKNaP

Comment: The first highlighted statement come from the immediately preceding equation $\angle GAF_2=\angle F'_2F_2A,$ since $\angle GAF_2$ and $\angle F'_2F_2A$ are alternate angles where the line $AF_2$ crosses $m$ and $F_2F_2'.$

Comment: The second highlighted statement seems to come out of nowhere. The proof appears invalid to me. There is no place where it actually uses any definition of an ellipse.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, even I thought so. The ellipse is never used in the proof. I am confused.

Comment: It seems this is a student paper from a large collection of such papers uploaded at about the same time. It probably did not have as thorough a review as a journal paper, and even in those papers a mistake sometimes sneaks through, especially when it is as inconsequential a mistake as this one (using an apparently circular argument to "prove" a very well-known fact along the way to doing something more interesting). I would focus instead on the proof in the answer below, which while it requires you to fill in some details, seems essentially sound to me.

Answer (score 3):

*Let's prove that normal $t$ to an angle bisector of $\angle ACB$ is tangent to ellipse with focuses at $A$ and $B$ at $C$.*

**Proof:** Let $B'$ be a reflection over $t$ and suppose that $t$ shares another point $D\ne C$ with ellipse. Then we have $$AD +DB' = AD+DB =AC+BC = AC+B'C = AB'$$ But this contradicts triangle inequality in $AB'D$ and we are done.
[image]

Comment: It might be worthwhile to include a proof of collinearity. Alternatively, you could construct $B'$ by extending $AC$ and then prove it is a reflection of $B$ in $t.$ That would be much like the construction quoted in the question. Of course the main difference between your proof and the one in the question is that yours works.

Comment: Yes, as @DavidK has mentioned, how do we know that $A$, $C$, and $B'$ lie on a straight line? Please help me with that. Once that is settled, your proof is beautiful.

Comment: @WhySee It is pretty obvious, since $t$ is *by assumption* perpendicular to the angular bisector. What happens with a point if it is consequently reflected about two perpendicular lines?